# Show that $ \kappa_2(A) \leq [\kappa_1(A) \kappa_{\infty} (A)]^{1/2}$

Tags: condition-number, matrix-norms

Suppose for a matrix $ A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $ \ ||A||_2  \leq ||A^TA||^{1/2}$, where $||.||$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ associated to matrix norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $||.||_2$ is a matrix $2-$ norm.

Show that $ \kappa_2(A) \leq [\kappa_1(A) \kappa_{\infty} (A)]^{1/2}$, 
 where $||.||_{\infty}$ matrix $\infty-$norm

and $\kappa$ denote the condition number .

**Answer:**

Since $||A||_2 \leq \sqrt{||A^T||||A||}$, we have

$\kappa_2(A) \leq \sqrt{\kappa_2(A) \kappa_{2}(A)}$,

Now if $ \kappa_2(A) \leq \kappa_1(A)$ and $\kappa_2(A) \leq \kappa_{\infty}(A)$, then we are done. **But is it possible?**

Comment: You might hope that $\| A \|_2 \leq \| A \|_1$ and $\| A \|_2 \leq \| A \|_\infty$, which would suffice to show this. This turns out to be false: a matrix with a big row sum and all small column sums will have a relatively small 1-norm, enough for the 2-norm to be bigger than the 1-norm. But in such a case it has a large infinity norm. This suggests that there is some interplay in the product, where the 1-norm being small gets compensated for by the infinity-norm being large and vice versa. Can you use this? The identity $\| Ax \|_2^2 = (Ax)^TAx$ is likely useful.

Comment: Also I don't really see what the condition $\| A \|_2 \leq \| A^T A \|^{1/2}$ means. If both norms are the usual Euclidean operator norm then $\| A \|_2 = \| A^T A \|_2^{1/2}$ as one can see immediately from the structure of the SVD. If you're using some other norm on $A^T A$ then it matters what that norm actually is.

Comment: @Ian, The condition $||A||_2 \leq |\sqrt{||A^TA||}$ is given in the question and it says we have to use it to prove this, where $||.||$ is a norm in $R^n$ associated with matrix norm $||.||$ on $R^{n \times n}$

Comment: But the given norm for $A^T A$ is totally arbitrary other than being an induced norm? I don't see how that can possibly be used. Maybe you should make sure you have the question copied correctly. It seems more likely to me that they are suggesting that you use the fact $\| A \|_2 = \| A^T A \|_2^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Ian, The question says $||.||$ is the subordinate matrix norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.